# ios5 uiwebview white content stripe bug

Tags: jquery, objective-c, ios, xcode, jquery-mobile

I am properly loading a jqueryMobile file proprely into an android webview, all known browsers and also safari mobile. All of them loads the content properly and scales it when rotated device. However, when loaded on an iOS uiwebview (tested on iOS5), white bottom stripe appears...! I tried several methods but unable to remove it. I found some information about this iOS bug but no solution yet. Any help would be aprreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have seen a similar instance near the top, it just required setting padding and margin to zero